# A question about DNS zone configuration file

Tags: dns

Why does the DNS zone configuration file carry "1912"?

[root@localhost redhat]# ls /etc | grep 1912

named.rfc1912.zones

Answer (score 1):

rfc1912 is [RFC 1912](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt); in particular that file on RedHat systems contains zones for various special purposes and "to help eliminate accidental queries for broadcast or local address to be sent off to the root nameservers" (section 4.1).